# PHP __soapCall Parms

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i have a SoapServer written in PHP and using this WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://myserver.net"  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="myService" targetNamespace="http://myserver.net">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:element name="getArticleStockInput">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="articleid" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="getArticleStockOutput">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="stock" type="xsd:float"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </wsdl:types> 
  <wsdl:message name="getArticleStockRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getArticleStockInput" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getArticleStockResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getArticleStockOutput" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="myServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="getArticleStock">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getArticleStockRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getArticleStockResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>   
  </wsdl:portType>  
  <wsdl:binding name="myServiceSoapHttpBinding" type="tns:myServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getArticleStock">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://myserver.net/getArticleStock"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ShopService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:myServiceSoapHttpBinding" name="ShopServiceSOAP11prt_HTTP">
      <soap:address location="http://myserver.net/ws.php5"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Now i am not sure how to call a WS-function in PHP.
Should i do it like this
What is the difference of the two possibilities ? 
I know, that i receive the parms in the Server in different ways, but what are the differences ?

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$url="http://myserver.net/wsdl.wsdl"; 
$client3 = new SoapClient($url);

$parray = array("articleid" => "150");          
$result = $client3->__soapCall("getArticleStock", array("getArticleStockInput"=>$parray));
```

or like this

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$url="http://myserver.net/wsdl.wsdl"; 
$client3 = new SoapClient($url);

$parray = array("articleid" => "150");          
$result = $client3->__soapCall("getArticleStock", $parray);
```

What is the right way to use ?

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP code snippet has been taken from the PHP manual of [__soapCall](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) function, which demonstrates the correct usage of the function:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
$client->SomeFunction($a, $b, $c);

$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c));
$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c), NULL, new SoapHeader(), $output_headers);

$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php", 'uri' => "http://test-uri/"));
$client->SomeFunction($a, $b, $c);
$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c));
$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c), array('soapaction' => 'some_action', 'uri' => 'some_uri'));
?>
```

Comment: thanks so far, but i read this always. i thought it depends on the wsdl file and possible complex types.